# cmd.exe starts my WPF Window behind the top window in Windows 8 only

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, cmd

My WPF Application is started via cmd file. The cmd file carries out multiple steps:

1. Initialize some variables
2. Start external cmd file to initialize Database (Using START myfile.cmd)
3. Start my Wpf Application (using START myWPFApp.exe)

Everything works as expected on Windows 7. However, when I run the exact same code on a Windows 8 machine, the WPF Window is displayed behind the top window. This is a problem, since if the user has a fullscreen window open, he will not notice that the application has started (except for the icon in the taskbar)

Here is my (simplified) code: 
Run.cmd

```
timeout 1
START StartDatabase.cmd
START SimpleWPFWindow.exe
```

StartDatabase.cmd

```
exit
```

SimpleWPFWindow.exe

```
Use any WPF Application here (e.g. WPF Application Template with empty Window)
```

My findings so far:

- When I remove the first line in Run.cmd (the timeout that simulates some logic), the application start correctly
- When I remove the external call (Item 2 above) from the cmd file, the application starts correctly
- Programmatically pulling the window to the front in my code is not an option since I use a splash screen and the same problem applies to the splashscreen (= it is displayed behind the top window)
- Using TopMost = true for the window does not work because in case of a startup problem the application displays an error message, that would be covered and not visible if topmost was true.

Can anybody explain to me why there is this difference in Win7 vs. Win8?
What can I do to avoid the problem?

Many thanks for any input!

Comment: How do you expect it to be on top if you don't set `TopMost = true`? Would you also end up with a `Blue` `Background` if you didn't set that to `Blue`?

Comment: When you open an application, it usually opens on top. I do not want it to stay on top, only appear on top when starting. I don't understand the your 2nd question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to display one of the windows you could start in minimum mode or not display at all with `start /min ...` or `start /b ...` respectively.

Comment: I know. Unfortunatley, it does not help with my problem. The Main (WPF) Application Window is still hidden behind the windows explorer.